# Browser not using cached data

Tags: node.js, http-caching

**Edit**: this was all due to a typo in `Cache-control` `max-age` setting, used a colon instead of an equal sign.

In my web application, I use socket.io to display images dynamically to clients, based on live input on the server side. On the client side, I basically use a `<img id="image"/>` and update its content along the lines of

```
var updateImage = socket.on("updateImage", function(src) {
    document.getElementById("image").src = src;
});
```

Images are all in a static database, so in order to speed up later transitions, I would like the client to cache all the images. Since modern browsers are caching pretty much everything, I only use a `<img id="precache" style="display:none"/>` and a mechanism looping over the database, loading each image in this container one after the other.

I can see the images start to be loaded and cached right after connecting to the server, for instance by monitoring network in dev-tools (on Qutebrowser) and by monitoring the size of my browser's cache directory.

However, when I subsequently try to dynamically change the displayed image, the network monitoring suggests that the requested image is downloaded again from the server, because the reported size in the dev-tools tab is the full size of the image, in contrast to the few bytes which are usually reported when the browser is using the cache. In accordance, the display transition is lagged by the time taken to download again the image.

Why doesn't the client use the cached data?

If it's of any relevance :

- Same behavior (lagged display transition) with Firefox
- The application is served by a simple node.js http server, static images are served along the lines of

  ```
   fs.readFile(imagePath, "UTF-8", function(err, file){
       res.writeHead(200, {
           "Content-Type": "image/svg+xml",
           "Cache-control": "max-age: 4800, must-revalidate"
       });
       res.end(file);
   });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Typo in Cache-control setting: use equal sign, not colon.

```
fs.readFile(imagePath, "UTF-8", function(err, file){
    ...
        /* was max-age: 4800 */
        "Cache-control": "max-age=4800, must-revalidate"
 ...
```